# Проблема с маршрутизацией laravel

Tags: laravel

Не работает маршрут в `/routes/web.php`:

```
Route::post('action', ['uses' => 'MainController@action']);
```

Сервер отвечает: `Internal server error (500)`

А при переносе функции в роутер все исполняется:

```
Route::post('upload', function ()
{
    foreach ($_FILES["uploaded_files"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == 0){
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["uploaded_files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = basename($_FILES["uploaded_files"]["name"][$key]);
            $newname = base_path().'/public/upload/'.$name;
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, iconv( 'utf-8', 'windows-1251', $newname ))){
                echo "Файл закачан:".$name."<br>";
              } else {
                $error_files[] = $name;
              }
        }
    }
});
```

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать обычную запись:

```
Route::post('action', 'MainController@action');
```

Не вспомню для чего `uses` используется, но по моему вы его не так используете.

Comment: Там вообще не работает обработка маршрутов, исполняется только код, который непосредственно в самом web.php

Comment: Неймспейсы указывали? `App\Http\Controllers\MainController@action` если у вас в стандартной папке контроллер

Comment: ну да, это ж artisan сам создал контроллер, но в файле web.php не идет вызов

Comment: В web.php нужно тоже указывать неймспейсы как я написал

Comment: после указания неймспес в фале web.php даже стартовый index.php не открывает, это понятное дела... проблема совсем не в пространстве имен

Comment: метод action public?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('upload', 'MainController@action');
```

И проверьте права выставленные на папку контроллеров. Может от туда скрипты не могут выполнятся. А вообще при ошибках сервера - смотрите логи чтобы не гадать.